# Possible to add a property to a JSON version of my class without it existing in the class?

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, properties

I have a `List<>` of objects. Their class doesn't have a 'colour' property (`String`) - but I can derive the value of this property for each list element right before serializing.

Is the only way to include this property in the JSON object to add it to the class and then serialize the whole thing?

Or is there a way/approach to adding a property that needs to appear in a JSON object that would otherwise be pretty useless in my class?

I know it's possible with all sorts of string manipulation methods but it doesn't feel right doing that.

I'm using **DataContractJsonSerializer**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [data contract surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) that transparently substitutes instances of your class with instances of another class. This new class can look like anything, but in your case it would simply have the additional `Colour` property.

The benefit here is that you keep the original type of the list items; the surrogates get created during the serialization process and your existing code will not need to touch them at all.

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I'm after. Thanks a lot Jon.

Answer (score 1):

I supose you can create a new class that inherits from your List of objects and adds the string that's unuseful on the principal class.

When creating the JSON just use the derived class, which will contain the added string value and inherits all the rest data from the original object.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Didn't think of that. But I suppose what I'm trying to avoid is redundancy and storing excessive data - and not only would I be storing a unnecessary property against my class (doing it the way I proposed), but doing it your way I'd also be storing a whole additional class. +1.

Comment: Yes... but if you don't want to directly manipulate the JSON string and you don't want to do it "the elegant way" by creating a new class... What alternative left us to solve your problem? Afaik there's no way to manipulate the JSON object once it's created, and, if it would be possible you'll be facing exactly the same problem, as your JSON object would be loaded on memory and the "garbage" data would be stored in it.

Comment: Mmm... didn't know about surrogations, I've just readed Jon's post. It looks very good.